# NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat - php error while fetching external image

Tags: php, imagick

I had this code and it was working fine till recently ,

```
$img = new Imagick();
$img->readImage($url);
$img->setImageCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$img->setImageCompressionQuality(60);
$img->stripImage();
header('Content-Type: image/'.$img->getImageFormat());
echo $img;
$img->clean();
```

I am trying to fetch following url

```
https://cdn.stimulatemind.com/bgi/aurora/desktop-1.jpg
```

But I get following error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat `/tmp/magick-3LWEFFuf' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544 in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/panel/index.php:11 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/httpdocs/panel/index.php(11): Imagick->readimage('https://cdn.sti...') #1
```

I was searching everywhere and I found no solution , I ran the command `convert -version`

```
Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-68 Q16 x86_64 2020-04-01 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: © 1999-2019 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC Modules OpenMP(3.1) 
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fontconfig freetype gslib jng jpeg lcms ltdl lzma openexr pangocairo png ps rsvg tiff wmf x xml zlib
```

Can Someone help me , I am struck.Thank you.

Comment: try to use readImageFile(fopen($url,'r'));

Comment: You may need to edit your policy.xml file in ImageMagick to give permission to use HTTPS. See https://imagemagick.org/source/policy.xml

Comment: @ChristianFelix : still I get the same error

Comment: @fmw42 : Permission is already granted